# "Unknown type "Upload". Did you mean "Float"?"

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, apollo-server, typegraphql

I want to use the graphql upload in my project, but I get this error:

> "Unknown type "Upload". Did you mean "Float"?"

when I upload the file. The solutions I found in the internet don't use the buildSchema inside ApolloServer config. An example solution:

```
import { GraphQLUpload } from 'graphql-upload';

const resolvers = {
  Upload: GraphQLUpload,
  Query: {
    uploads: (parent, args) => {},
  },
  Mutation: {
    singleUpload: async (_, {file}) => {
      const {createReadStream, filename, mimetype, encoding} = await file;
      const stream = createReadStream();

      // Rest of your code: validate file, save in your DB and static storage

      return {filename, mimetype, encoding};
    },
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});
```

In my case if I type the "Upload: GraphQLUpload" line inside buildSchema:

```
import { GraphQLUpload } from 'graphql-upload';

const typeDefs = gql`
        scalar Upload

        type File {
            filename: String!
            mimetype: String!
            encoding: String!
        }

        type Query {
            otherFields: Boolean!
        }

        type Mutation {
            uploadFile(file: Upload!): File!
        }
    `;

const server = new ApolloServer({
        typeDefs,
        schema: await buildSchema({
            Upload: GraphQLUpload,
            resolvers: [
                PostResolver, 
                UserResolver, 
                LikeResolver,
                UploadResolver,
            ],
            validate: false,
        }),
        cache: 'bounded',
        context: ({ req, res }): MyContext => ({ 
            req, 
            res,
        }),
    });
```

I get this error:

> An argument of the type "{ Upload: GraphQLScalarType<unknown, unknown>; resolvers: [typeof PostResolver, typeof UserResolver, typeof LikeResolver, typeof UploadResolver]; validate: boolean; }" cannot be assigned to a parameter of the type "BuildSchemaOptions".
> An object literal can use only known properties. "Upload" does not exist in the "BuildSchemaOptions" type.

This is my UploadResolver file:

```
import path from 'path';
import { finished } from 'stream/promises';

export class UploadResolver {
    async uploadFile(_: any, { file }: any ) {
        const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = await file;

        // Invoking the `createReadStream` will return a Readable Stream
        const stream = createReadStream();

        const pathName = path.join(__dirname, `./public/img/post/${filename}`);

        const out = require('fs').createWriteStream(pathName);
        stream.pipe(out);
        await finished(out);

        return { filename, mimetype, encoding };
    }
}
```

So basically I need to find a way to define the "Upload" type in resolver or ApolloServer config.

**UPDATE:**

I've updated my resolver. Typescript understands type declarations, so everything is right I guess. But I still get the error when I upload the image, it states:

> Variable "$file" got invalid value {}; Upload value invalid

I don't know, it seems like graphql doesn't even get the file that is posted. Can it be linked to the fact I have client and server separated from each other?

UploadResolver:

```
@ObjectType() // GraphQL object
class FileResponse {
    @Field()
    filename!: string;

    @Field()
    mimetype!: string;

    @Field()
    encoding!: string;
}

@InputType()
class FileInput {
    @Field(() => GraphQLUpload)
    file: FileUpload
}

@Resolver()
export class UploadResolver {
    @Mutation(() => FileResponse)
    async uploadFile(
        @Arg('file', () => FileInput) { file }: FileInput,
    ): Promise<FileResponse> {
        const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = await file;

        // Invoking the `createReadStream` will return a Readable Stream
        const stream = createReadStream();

        const pathName = path.join(__dirname, `./public/img/post/${filename}`);

        const out = require('fs').createWriteStream(pathName);
        stream.pipe(out);
        await finished(out);

        return { filename, mimetype, encoding };
    }
}
```

GraphQL mutation file:

```
mutation UploadFile($file: FileInput!) {
    uploadFile(file: $file) {
        filename
        mimetype
        encoding
    }
}
```

ApolloClient code snippet:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: createUploadLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:8080/graphql',
  }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

Here I apply graphqlUploadExpress in index.ts from server side

```
app.use(graphqlUploadExpress({ maxFileSize: 10000, maxFiles: 10 }));
```

Here's my function to handle upload

```
const [, uploadFile] = useUploadFileMutation();

    const handleFileChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<any>) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        if(!file) return false;
        uploadFile({ file: file });
    }
```

Comment: See [this example project](https://github.com/carlocorradini/graphmarket/blob/c02a0b902979c10262847e50414a742c54156cd8/packages/graphmarket-service-products/src/resolvers/ProductResolver.ts#L108).
You must inform `typegraphql` what is the correct type of the given argument (`GraphQLUpload`).
Moreover, note that your resolver is not correct, you must follow `typegraphql` guide (e.g. @Resolver(), @Arg(), ...)

Comment: @CarloCorradini I did it exactly like in your project, but got the following error: Unknown type "GraphQLUpload". Do you know how to tell Graphql what GraphQLUpload is? I mean I have some custom types in my project already, but they all are @InputType() with @Field()'s, so I guess it's not what I need to do with GraphQLUpload scalar

Comment: @CarloCorradini Note: I used the 'mutation UploadFile($file: GraphQLUpload!)' line in mutation graphql file

Comment: You must follow typegraphql syntax. The @Field must have the correct return type (i.e. @Field(()=>GraphQLUpload) otherwise the type is unknown.

Comment: @CarloCorradini okay, i specified the return type. But when uploading I get this error: "Variable "$file" got invalid value {}; Upload value invalid". It means that I pass nothing to the server, but when I console.log() it it shows the File object. I've been searching for the solution for 3 hours and none of these answers work. You're my last hope, please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Do you want to share the code?

Comment: @CarloCorradini okay, I've updated the post, check it out

Comment: `@Arg('file', () => FileInput) { file }` should be `Args(..)` not `@Arg(...)`

Comment: @CarloCorradini there is no such thing as 'Args', I'm just getting an "Args was declared but value never read" error. And you use @Arg(...) in your project.

Comment: Try not to do objects destructuring and put `file` in single @Arg and not InputType

Comment: @CarloCorradini i get the same error if i use @Arg('file', () => GraphQLUpload) { file }: FileUpload

Comment: Mhmhmh it's better if you can share the code because now I really don't know what is the cause